# Python3 Request from API return Not Found

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to get a balance from some address at a explorer on Python but I get 404 error and I believe that is related to a list.

This is my code:

```html
import urllib.request, json, requests

listAddress = [
    "HiaRFZkLiWaUuu2x3Dxg2rAMu6BTrzoitf"
]
explorerUrl = 'http://explorer.htmlcoin.com'
urlBase = '/api/tokens/Hj5mkJmDWKq8HAh9qDYLnbohZHw6kaUG3A/addresses/'
balance = '/balance'


for address in listAddress:
    urlGamb = explorerUrl+urlBase+address+balance
    json_data = urlGamb
    r = requests.post(json_data)
    r.status_code
    r.json()
    print(r.json())
```

The problem is that returns this error:

```
python3 newwork.py 
{'status': 404, 'url': '/api/tokens/Hj5mkJmDWKq8HAh9qDYLnbohZHw6kaUG3A/addresses/HiaRFZkLiWaUuu2x3Dxg2rAMu6BTrzoitf/balance', 'error': 'Not found'}
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor suggestion:

```py
urlGamb = f"{explorerUrl}{urlBase}{address}{balance}"
```

I don't know about the API, you did not provide a link, but the value of `urlGamb` is `'http://explorer.htmlcoin.com/api/tokens/Hj5mkJmDWKq8HAh9qDYLnbohZHw6kaUG3A/addresses/HiaRFZkLiWaUuu2x3Dxg2rAMu6BTrzoitf/balance'` and that is not JSON. The assignment to `json_data` seems like a conceptual error because the URL string is not json. If the `post` requires a JSON payload then the docs should tell you how to construct it.

Should the `post` have been a `get` request instead? That would make sense because according to REST standards, `post` is for changing state on the server, and you are only making a query.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the awesome help, I forgot to say that I can get with object too, but maybe was a mistake (I am not good at python).

Here the object version:

http://explorer.htmlcoin.com/api/tokens/Hj5mkJmDWKq8HAh9qDYLnbohZHw6kaUG3A/addresses/HiaRFZkLiWaUuu2x3Dxg2rAMu6BTrzoitf/balance?format=object

I will try like you said. Thanks

Comment: Mike Just to let you and any other people know that your tip worked. Thanks a lot.

Code Working:

```
import urllib.request, json, requests

listAddress = [
    "HiaRFZkLiWaUuu2x3Dxg2rAMu6BTrzoitf"
]
explorerUrl = 'http://explorer.htmlcoin.com'
urlBase = '/api/tokens/Hj5mkJmDWKq8HAh9qDYLnbohZHw6kaUG3A/addresses/'
balance = '/balance'


for address in listAddress:
    urlGamb = f"{explorerUrl}{urlBase}{address}{balance}"
    json_data = urlGamb
    r = requests.get(json_data)
    r.status_code
    r.json()
    print(r.json())
```